# Ask constraint questions when creating image objects in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, image, dom, canvas, browser

I tried to create an [image object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) by uploading an image file of **170MB** Chrome Browser.

However, the error as below is occurring.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFzzs.png)

What's the cause?

Is there a size constraint on creating an image object?

```
const loadFromFile = (file: File) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new CustomFileReader()
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
    reader.onerror = (e) => reject(e)
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  })
}

const createImage = (dataUrl) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = (error) => { // generate Error Event
      console.log('image load error', e)
      reject(e)
    }
    img.src = dataUrl
  })
}

const load = async (file: File) => {
   const dataUrl = await loadFromFile(file)  // successful
   const image = await createImage(dataUrl)  // error
}
```

This is the image used for the test: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/La_crucifixi%C3%B3n%2C_by_Juan_de_Flandes%2C_from_Prado_in_Google_Earth.jpg/2560px-La_crucifixi%C3%B3n%2C_by_Juan_de_Flandes%2C_from_Prado_in_Google_Earth.jpg

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't match your code... But for a starter, stop using a FileReader. To display an Image from Blob create a blob: URI from it (`createObjectURL(blob)`)

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido for your reply.

Do you mean I should use `createObjectURL(blob)`?

Comment: Yes, but this will probably not fix your current issue.  According to the error message the error happens somewhere else in your code, in a part you don't show.

Comment: @Kaiido The above error occurs when **loading** a **170MB file** into the **new Image()**.

Comment: The error message on the console is the same as that.

Comment: The same error occurs when trying with `createObjectURL (blob)`.

Comment: When creating a `new Image() object`, are there any limitations on image size?

Comment: @Kaiido My ultimate goal is to create `Canvas` using `Image objects`.
However, the above **error event** occurs at the time of **loading a large image file as an Image object**.

Comment: Is there a way to see Stacktrace in detail using an error event?

Comment: The stack trace says it was fired in `compressImage`, the Error event doesn't have a `target`. The only reason for this to fail "because of the size" would be a lack of memory. However it's also possible that your imag fails for an other reason, e.g it could be corrupted. Are you able to open that file from the browser directly, without going through your code (drop the file in the address bar)

Comment: @Kaiido As you said, I think it could be a problem with low memory. 
Image does not load when dropped on empty tab.